# Adding Custom Controls to a panel programatically with margin

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

Hello I made a custom text box with an associated label.
and I have a custom Form.

when on a form if I drag drop my custom textbox from the toolbox and set it's properties I can see that it works. However what I would like to do is when I'm on my custom control where I have a TableLayoutPanel (with 3 rows)
on row index 1(mid row) I would like to add my custom controls programatically.

when I do this the text label is somewhere else then the textbox.

My Code and the Image to my problem is below:

**MyCustomTextBox:**

```
public class MyLbTextBox : TextBox
{       
    #region CustomProperties

    private Label AssociatedLabel = new Label();
    private string _myLbText;

    public string MyTextLabel
    {
        get => _myLbText;
        set
        {              
            _myLbText = value;              
            AssociatedLabel.Text = _myLbText ?? _myBindingField;
            Size s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(AssociatedLabel.Text, AssociatedLabel.Font);
            AssociatedLabel.Location =
                new Point(Location.X - s.Width - AssociatedLabel.Padding.Right, Location.Y);
            var MyMargin = this.Margin;
            MyMargin.Left = 100;
            this.Margin = MyMargin;
        }
    }


    #endregion

    private string _myBindingField;

    public string MyBindingField
    {
        get { return _myBindingField; }
        set
        {
            _myBindingField = value; 

        }
    }

    private MyJoins.MyExpressions _myExpression;

    public MyJoins.MyExpressions MyExpression
    {
        get => _myExpression;
        set => _myExpression = value;
    }

    public MyLbTextBox()
    {
        _myExpression = MyJoins.MyExpressions.Equals;
        ParentChanged += MyLbTextBox_ParentChanged;
        LocationChanged += MyLbTextBox_LocationChanged;
        Disposed += MyLbTextBox_Disposed;
    }

    private void MyLbTextBox_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AssociatedLabel.Dispose();
    }

    private void MyLbTextBox_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Size s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(AssociatedLabel.Text, AssociatedLabel.Font);
        AssociatedLabel.Location =
            new Point(Location.X - s.Width - AssociatedLabel.Padding.Right, Location.Y);
    }

    private void MyLbTextBox_ParentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AutoAddAssociatedLabel();
    }

    private void AutoAddAssociatedLabel()
    {
        if (Parent == null) return;

        AssociatedLabel.Padding = new Padding(3);

        Size s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(AssociatedLabel.Text, AssociatedLabel.Font);
        AssociatedLabel.Location =
            new Point(Location.X - s.Width - AssociatedLabel.Padding.Right, Location.Y);

        Parent.Controls.Add(AssociatedLabel);
    }
}
```

[image]

By the way, this is how I add my controls:

[image]

after adding my controls through the property grid

this is how I set them on the screen

```
private void _mySearchFields_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_mySearchFields == null) return;
        foreach (var searchField in _mySearchFields)
        {
            if (MySearchFieldsPanel.Contains(searchField.MyControl)) continue;
            MySearchFieldsPanel.Controls.Add(searchField.MyControl, 1, 0);               
        }
        var myHeight = MySearchFieldsPanel.Controls.Cast<Control>().Sum(variable => variable.Height);
        MyBdPanel.RowStyles[1].Height = myHeight + 40;
    }
```

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

This line is a reason of all problems:

```
Parent.Controls.Add(AssociatedLabel);
```

This is bad idea if you are creating composite controls (composite = consisting from several *real* controls). That will cause layout problems you have experienced and more.

Instead consider either:

1. Utilize `UserControl` to create composition.
2. Create custom control (like you do) but **without** more controls. If you need label - draw it as text in `OnPaint` while allocating some space: *fixed* with margin, adjustable with some property or dynamic with measuring text.